# How to give link to a cell based on condition in antd table?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using Antd table and showing tree structure. I want to give link to a column based on condition i.e. if row data is related to device then column1 should have hyperlink else display just plain text.

How can I do that?